# Richtext in TFS2010 Testcase Teststeps' texts?

Tags: tfs-sdk, microsoft-test-manager

I am currently evaluating possible solutions to limitations in Microsoft's Test Manager 2010 TestStep Editor control and I was wondering whether anyone knows if and if so, how you can write richtext to the Action and Expected Result fields of a step? As far as I saw it takes a '[ParameterizedString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.parameterizedstring.aspx)' as input, but I am not sure what parameters MSDN refers to (or the MTM TestRunner can handle) when saying "[...]Represents a string that has embedded parameters.[...]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Expected Results string is a list of string namees delimited by spaces, semi-colons or commas.  You can enter something like: @Test, @Cart, @Book or @Test @Cart @Book.

You can't add HTML to the Expected Result parameters or the action; however, I am not sure I would describe this as a limitation.  What action were you thinking you would need to be able to do this.  Actions are typically "Click this" or "Go to here"  Did you just want a stronger visual queue for certain parts of the action?

Here is an article that describes the intent with the [expected results section](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/06/22/wctfs_create-test-case.aspx):

> The real power of the test case though, comes in the bottom portion of
>   the screen, on the Steps tab. This is where you list out the manual
>   steps the tester will use to test the application. Start typing where
>   it says "Click here to add a step." In the Action column, you add the
>   action that the tester should try and perform, such as "Open Internet
>   Explorer." In the Expected Results column, you list what should happen
>   when the action is performed, such as "Internet Explorer opens to its
>   default home page." To continue adding new steps to the test case, hit
>   Enter to go to a new line.
>
> Not every action step requires an expected result. When an expected
>   result is specified, it turns that step into a verification step. With
>   a verification step, the tester will have to specify whether that
>   particular step was successful or not.
>
> You have the ability to provide parameters to your test steps. This
>   allows you to run the test multiple times, each time using a different
>   value. An example of this would be testing different login values on a
>   Web site. Instead of creating a new test case for each login, you can
>   create one test case, and pass multiple login values into it.

Comment: alright a no-go is a good enough answer aswell for the time being (they showed that vNext does in fact support richtext down to test steps level, was wondering whether 2010 already 'supported' it and maybe just not having the necessary UI bits in place).

Comment: The reason why richtext is a requirement in our case lies in the history of the 10.000+ test cases with about 30-50 steps each we'll migrate over to TFS. Our current test steps are rather long (we also hit the ~350 (visualizable) chars limit in the actions/exp. results fields) and restructuring into smaller (but more) steps is not an option right now due to time limitations. Different process / methodology, growth over the past 10 years etc results into this unfortunate constraint.

Comment: I see yeah that makes a lot more sense now.  Sounds like good times :)  I am sure your team can come up with a crafy way to import but if you need help let me know.